# opening PDF in harmon.ie

Tags: outlook-addin, sharepoint-online, harmon.ie

we have an issue when we try to open a PDF file in sharepoint using harmon.ie addin in outlook. 
we double click the file, Adobe loads and give an error saying an error happen when opening the document. The access path is invalid.(my error is in french)
If we browse sharepoint in explorer, we can open the same file with no issue.
Any idea?

Comment: On-premise or SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download latest 6.4 harmon.ie version from harmon.ie web site, copy all the below lines inside a .reg file. Register it (double click on it) and restart Outlook. It should then work.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\OpenPDFWithWebDav]
@="false"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Mainsoft\Prefs\OpenPDFWithWebDav]
@="false"

Answer (score 0):

Your PDF viewer does probably not work WebDAV.
Register the below registry key and restart Outlook.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\AcrobatSPI]
@="false"

----- Jean

Comment: i just tried it and no luck...but... we are using acrobat dc pro. if we use acrobat viewer dc it works.

Comment: Download latest 6.4 harmon.ie version from harmon.ie web site.